# Extract Fiscal Year with R Lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'll create several dates.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- ymd(c("2012-03-26", "2012-05-04", "2012-09-23", "2012-12-31"))
```

I can extract the year and quarter from these `x` values.

`quarter(x, with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10)`

`[1] 2012.2 2012.3 2012.4 2013.1`

But I can't seem to extract *just* the fiscal year. This doesn't work, but what will?

`year(x, with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10)`

I receive the following error message:

> Error in year(x, with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10) : 
>         unused arguments (with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10)

Comment: What about `as.integer(quarter(x, with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10))` ?

Comment: `lubridate::year(x)` works for me. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `lubridate::year(x)` is for the *calendar year*. I'm looking for the *fiscal year*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't mind an additional step, you could then extract the first 4 characters of your quarters to get just the years.

```r
library(lubridate)

x <- ymd(c("2012-03-26", "2012-05-04", "2012-09-23", "2012-12-31"))

q <- quarter(x, with_year = TRUE, fiscal_start = 10)
q
#> [1] 2012.2 2012.3 2012.4 2013.1

fy <- stringr::str_sub(q, 1, 4)
fy
#> [1] "2012" "2012" "2012" "2013"
```

Comment: `quarter()` might behave differently than anticipated, see here https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/682

Answer (score 4):

```
df <- data.frame(x)
fiscal_start = 10

# with base R
df$fy <- ifelse(month(df$x) >= fiscal_start, year(df$x) + 1, year(df$x))

# or with dplyr:
dplyr::mutate(df, fy = ifelse(month(x) >= fiscal_start, year(x) + 1, year(x)))
```

This produces:

```
           x   fy
1 2012-03-26 2012
2 2012-05-04 2012
3 2012-09-23 2012
4 2012-12-31 2013
```